# How can I get Razor to resolve symbol @Model?

Tags: c#, razor

I have a Razor .cshtml template with the following:

[image]

As you can see, `@Model` can't be resolved.

However, when I parse the template with the following code:

```
public static string RenderPartialViewToString(string templatePath, string viewName, List<ZonesVM> zonesVm)
{
    string text = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(templatePath, viewName));

    string renderedText = Razor.Parse(text, zonesVm);
    return renderedText;
}
```

it works correctly, and I see the result I expect to in the HTML.

Is there a way for me to get Razor to know what @Model is before it's compiled?

For reference, I'm using [RazorEngine](http://razorengine.codeplex.com/) and not the ordinary MVC Razor stuff.

Comment: you don't need the `@` there for one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>include `@model My.Super.ModelObject` at the top of the .cshtml</strike>

<strike>**edit** I see the issue now... looking further</strike>

**edit 2** Something like below works with MVC Razor (never used RazorEngine... so it may not translate 100%)

```
@foreach (var item in Model.list)
{        
    <h1>@item.Value</h1>
}
```

It works with Intellisense as well. (this is MVC 4 VS2010)

Comment: guess I should have posted this as an answer instead of a comment after all

Answer (score 6):

You're already in a code block.  You don't need the @ before model.  The @ is used to transition into a code block from html.

Comment: This is the real answer don't know why is the other accepted.